# nginx svelte django(waitress) external ip no response

Tags: django, nginx, svelte

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
// nginx.conf
server {
  listen       8888;
  server_name  xxx.xx.xxx.xx; // my PC's external ip 
  root         html;
}
```

and I'm running a django/waitress server on xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8072

This is my svelte code fetching data from the django server

```js
const res = await fetch(`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8072/myapp/`);
```

I built this svelte app and copied the content of the public folder to nginx/html and ran nginx.
'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8888/myapp' gives me no response from the django server.

However, if I fetch from 'localhost:8072' and run the django server on locahost:8072, and configure nginx with
`server_name 'localhost'`, this work properly.

Why is this not working with an external IP?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Just checking, have you enabled port forwarding on your modem for port 8888?

Comment: Yes, of course! django/waitress/nginx without svelte working.
but svelte build files in nginx html folder don't work..

Comment: You might need to share some more code for us to help find the issue, do you have a repo so we can reproduce?